# Apache arrow, alignment and padding

Tags: python-3.x, alignment, padding, simd, apache-arrow

I want to use apache arrow because it  enables execution engines to take advantage of the latest SIMD (Single input multiple data) operations included in modern processors, for native vectorized optimization of analytical data processing. (https://arrow.apache.org/).

From documentration (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/memory_layout.html), I understand that memory allocation     make sure about 64 byte alignment.

In order to verify this 64 bytes alignment, I use the __array_interface__ data member of a numpy array that points to the data-area storing the array contents and compute a modulo 64 on it. If the result is 0 then the memory address is aligned on at least 64 Bytes.

When I execute the code bellow, on my system (Fedora) it seems to work (the result of modulo 64 is zero) but when I execute the same code on my colleague's system (Fedora too) it does not work: the result of modulo 64 is not zero. So the memory is not aligned on 64 bytes.

Please find my code here:

```
import pyarrow as pa

tab=pa.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

panda_array=tab.to_pandas()

print('numpy address {} modulo 64 => {}'.format(panda_array.__array_interface__['data'][0], panda_array.__array_interface__['data'][0]%64))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "does not work" is pretty vague.  What exactly do you get?  [mcve].

Comment: I agree and I apologize, I edit my post again and I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Much better, now you have a clear and specific question.  If I knew anything about python and apache-arrow, I'd probably be able to answer it.  (I do my SIMD in asm and C/C++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory in Arrow is 64 byte aligned but in your example code, the conversion to Pandas/NumPy makes a copy of the data as a nested array of lists is differently represented in Arrow and in NumPy. In Arrow this is done using one buffer that holds the data of all lists while there is another buffer that holds the offsets for each list in that Array. As NumPy has no native list type, it is represented as a NumPy array that contains other NumPy arrays as elements. These are represented in the first NumPy array as Python objects.

Thus using the NumPy functions you see the memory as allocated by NumPy, not by Arrow. Thus if your memory address is on a 64 byte boundary, it is only by chance.

In the next version (0.9) of `pyarrow` there will be a `buffers` property to access the underlying memory addresses. You should then be able to directly check if the Arrow memory is allocated on a 64 byte aligned address (it always should be).

Comment: In your first paragraph, did you mean 64 *byte* aligned?  8-byte alignment doesn't help much for most SIMD instruction sets.

Comment: Yes I meant 64 byte. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid copy during  Arrow to Pandas/NumPy conversion.
? Arrow documentation indicates zero-copy processes:
"The Arrow memory format supports zero-copy reads for lightning-fast data access without serialization overhead"

Comment: This is sadly only possible on a very small set of Pandas DataFrames due to the BlockManager internals. For the Pandas Series / NumPy case, many of the conversions are zero-copy, but only those for which a native NumPy types exists. These all the int* and float* types as well as the categorical type in Pandas.