# Apache arrow, alignment of numpy array with zero copy

Tags: python, numpy, apache-arrow

I convert an arrow object with « zero copy », to panda, but the result object is not aligned.

```
#create a pyarrow.table.Table from parquet file
pq_file=pq.ParquetFile(parquet_file_name)
arrow_table=pq_file.read()

#convert pyarrow.table.Table to panda with zero copy
df=arrow_table.to_pandas(zero_copy_only=True)

#check if the numpy array is aligned :
print("alignment: {}".format(df.as_matrix().__array_interface__['data'[0]%64))
```

Code return: `alignment: 16`

Conclusion: The NumPy array is not aligned.As I convert pyarrow.table.Table to panda with “zero copy”, I conclude that the pyarrow.table.Table itself is not aligned. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48830024/1531971

Answer (score 2):

Response from uwe:

1. I’m not sure if the `zero_copy_only` Flag is working correctly in
   Arrow 0.8, we have made recently some fixes (but not released them
   yet).
2. There is a new `buffers` property in the upcoming
   release, where you can also check the memory address of the PyArrow
   Arrow. This is useful to verify in Python that the zero copy was
   really zero copy.
3. You need to be aware that `df.as_matrix()` may
   also do a copy if you don’t have a DataFrame that has a single
   DType.